# Qmlscene from Launcher Icon

Tags: bash, launcher

I'm currently developing an application just for myself on Ubuntu desktop using Ubuntu SDK. I've been trying to make an executable on the desktop/launcher to start the application from the desktop.

I've created an icon that can be run as an executable and on the command under Properties->Command on the launcher I've put:

```
qmlscene ~/file/path/main.qml
```

When entered into the terminal this same way, the application starts how I would like it to. But when launched from the desktop icon, only `qmlscene` pops up that I then have to manually follow the path to main.qml

Does anyone know how to correctly launch an application from the launcher icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$HOME` instead of `~` (tilde).

Tilde is `bash` specific. In `bash` tilde automatically expands to the `$HOME` value.

It has no special meaning, except for `bash`. See the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion) for further details about tilde expansion.

Your launcher `Exec` command should be:

```
Exec=bash -c "qmlscene $HOME/file/path/main.qml"
```

---

**Edit**: My test launcher

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Myapp
Comment=Myapp
Exec=bash -c "qmlscene $HOME/foo.qml"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Qt;
TargetEnvironment=Unity
StartupWMClass=do-not-directly-run-firestorm-bin
StartupNotify=true
```

Comment: So I've created a new .desktop file with the new Exec=qmlscene $HOME/file/path/main.qml, but it still only opens to the home directory to let me manually find the .qml file.

Comment: @QandA I've updated my answer to include a bash command, please try this version

Comment: This instead just gives me an error: "There was an error launching the application". Does the command/exec run like it would in a terminal (except for the differences in ~ and $HOME)?

Comment: @QandA: Could you please adapt to your path my sample launcher?

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! It does directly open the qml file now. I'm not sure why it works now though. Before I did not include TargetEnvironment,StartupWMClass, or StartupNotify.